# Macintosh HD drive listing as Recovery Partition and it is not available to boot

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I just wanted to merge 2 NTFS drives because I want to increase size of my BootCamp partition. But now, I can't boot to macOS. I can see it when I boot to Windows; its files and everything ok, but somewhy it is listed as Macintosh HD (D:) and my Recovery Partition is listed as Recovery HD (E:).

When I open Startup Menu, only my Bootcamp and Recovery partitions are avaible to select, no Macintosh HD.

Here is my Disk Management screen from Windows. My Macintosh HD (371GB) drive listed as "Recovery Partition"

[image]

How can I repair my main disk...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the first step, in reconstructing messed up the partition tables, is to dump the current contents.

If running High Sierra (macOS 10.13), you would need to boot to [internet, internal or USB based macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). The following commands would partially dump the contents of the GPT and MBR partition table.

```
gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0
fdisk  /dev/disk0
```

The partition tables can then be repaired by using a variety of tools. A well known third party tool is [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).

Since you can only boot to Windows, the `gpt` and `fdisk` commands would be unavailable. There are [third party Windows equivalents](https://sourceforge.net/projects/readgpt/) named `readgpt.exe` and `readmbr.exe` that can dump the contents of the partition tables. The syntax for executing these commands is shown below.

> Note: These commands have to be run from a "Administrator: Command Prompt" window.

```
readgpt  -t0
readmbr  -t0
```

Additionally, the following command will dump the GPT attributes.

```
readgpt  -a0
```

There also a Windows version of the [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) command. Below is the syntax for executing this command from a "Administrator: Command Prompt" window.

```
gdisk64  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
```

If you have trouble using the `gdisk` command, you can post the partition table information in your question and ask for help.